# Failed to run EXE generated by PyInstaller when I change EXE name

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm having trouble changing exe name to other name except main, that is to say, EXE works well only when it's name is "main", is there any dependency about the exe name? my project named "studio" and I generate studio.exe in output directory, but I failed to run exe with the error following:
output on console:

```
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 17
```

While I change name to "main", I don't have such error above. After tried many ways I can't figure out why, anyone perhaps have good idea? thanks

Comment: Issue seems to be related to the pyinstaller output based on a quick check of the error. Are you able to post a source repo so this can be attempted locally? Without that there's not much that can be done to troubleshoot since there are many possibilities, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Use the `-n`/`--name` option to specify the name of the executable when you run pyinstaller, rather than renaming the executable afterwards:

```
python pyinstaller.py --name=studio
```

You can refer to the discussion below for an in-depth analysis of the issue:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1106

Excerpt from codewarrior0's comments:

> The above error is caused by the bootloader using the filename of its
> exe to derive the filename of the manifest to load using CreateActCtx.
> The error occurs because the application manifest is not found when
> the onefile exe is renamed.